# Redux Dev Tools - show more dispatched actions?

Tags: redux, redux-devtools

The Redux Dev Tools shows a certain amount of dispatched actions for the time travel feature - is there a way to increase that default amount?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [maxAge](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/master/docs/API/Arguments.md#maxage) option:

> number (>1) - maximum allowed actions to be stored in the history tree. The oldest actions are removed once `maxAge` is reached. It's critical for performance. Default is `50`.

E.g.

```js
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({ maxAge: 5 });
```

Switch to the redux dev tools tab. There are always only five action histories.

[image]

Or, you can set this option in the redux dev tools browser extension.

The option: **Limit the action history to xx items.**

[image]